# What is the most appropriate way to handle authorization when users can have multiple roles in multiple places in dotnet CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, roles

I have a NET CORE application where users can have multiple roles; SiteEmployee, SiteAdmin and CompanyAdmin. All these roles are associated with a specific site/company. A user can have different roles in different places (you can be a SiteEmployee in a site, and a CompanyAdmin in a Company at the same time). Using roles means that the [Authorize(Roles=”CompanyAdmin”)] will allow him access in ALL companies, not just in the one he should have access to.

Right now I handle this by using the ASP.Net roles and having users assigned to sites/companies in tables in the database as well.
I realized that I only use the roles for checking the access to controller methods by using [Authorize(Roles=”SiteEmployee”)], but in the methods i ALSO have to check to see if the user is even a part of that specific site. That means I have to authorize the user two times.
Using roles seems redundant, but this also seems like a problem others will have had. So there must be a decent solution for this.

So my question is this: What is the most appropriate way to handle this authorization?

I looked into implementing my own version of Authorize, and taking a parameter from the method that implements it, but as far as I can tell, that is not possible.
I also looked into using Resource-based authorization, but I’m not sure that is really what I need.

Comment: Have you thought to use Claims based authorization ?

Comment: Claim based authorization raises the same problem

Comment: There is some discussion of the issue here. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/885301/be-secure-from-insecure-direct-object-reference. Essentially you have gone as far as you can using Role Based Authorisation, which is the first level of checks. You now need an Access Control List of some sort (ACL) or if your requirements are basic enough, a second level of checks as shown in 'Data Access Control' in the linked article `if (account.UserId != User.Identity.GetUserId())
       {
           return new HttpUnauthorizedResult("User is not Authorized.");
       }`

Comment: @DaveSatchell Thanks for the link ! i'll get to reading

Comment: It's long. Essentially, having the two checks isn't the worst way to go, as it provides a bit of 'defense in depth' using multiple layers. I would recommend checking within the method that the user has access to view that requested object, but if you have complex requirements and prefer to use a framework you should be able to seek one out online.

Comment: @DaveSatchell It's seems that the article describes the problem and a possible solution, if you want to post your message as an answer i'll mark it is the solution. Thanks for the help !

Comment: What about policy-based authorization? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Also an option. A little more complex, but a valid way of doing it. I prefer the explanation here: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/11/policy-based-authorization-in-aspnet-core